# Finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1+2^2+3^3+4^4+\cdots +n^n}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, fractions

Finding $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1+2^2+3^3+4^4+\cdots +n^n}{n^n}$$

Attempt: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\frac{1}{n^n}+\frac{2^2}{n^n}+\frac{3^3}{n^n}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{n^n}{n^n}\bigg] = 1$$

because all terms are approaching to zero except last terms

but answer is not $1$ , could some help me to solve it , thanks

Comment: What is the answer, if it is not $1$?

Comment: Indeed, I read too fast. Sorry about that. (I have retracted my vote to close).

Comment: @ robjohn it was given by my friend and told me answer is not $1$.

Comment: Can we take $n^n$ common here? from both numerator and denominator?

Comment: This supposed duplicate is not the same question. Here it is $\sum k^k$ while the other one is $\sum k^n$. They should be dissociated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounding by a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series),
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{n^n}{n^n}+\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}+\frac{(n-2)^{n-2}}{n^n}+\cdots+\frac{1^1}{n^n}\\
&\le1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{n}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
Since the sum is obviously always $\ge1$, and $\le\frac{n}{n-1}$, the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) says that the limit is $1$.

Comment: Is this sandwich theorem?

Comment: @ItiShree: In the Wikipedia article cited above, the Squeeze Theorem is also known as the Sandwich Theorem and the Pinching Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

By Stolz  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1+2^2+3^3+4^4+\cdots +n^n}{n^n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^n}{n^n-(n-1)^{n-1}}=1$$

Comment: thanks Michel Rozenberg for nice solution. can we solve it without Stolz method.